# Error message on empty EDOffice1 file

Tags: vb.net, vba

I successfully designed a code to compute the regression analysis by clicking a command button. The command codes make reference to an excel sheet imported into VB. I want an error message to pup up when the user hits the computational command button without first importing the data in to VB. I did this as a trap but does not work:

If EDOffice1.ActiveDocument Is Empty Then

MsgBox "No Files were selected"

End If

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
If EDOffice1.Documents.Count = 0 Then
     MsgBox "No Files were selected"
End If
```

Also consider disabling the button, until the data is imported.

Comment: I tried the first option and came with error "Run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method"